# Iterate through csv files and plot with ggplot in R

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I have a series of csv files in one directory. The csv files share the same format.

I wish to iterate through all of the csv files and plot a graph per csv file.

The (tested) function to plot the graph is as follows:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Count_norm, y = duration_in_traffic), data = tmp) + geom_point(aes(color = id)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))
```

I have attempted to iterate over the csv files and then plot each by:

```
setwd("/Users/testdata/")
filenames = dir(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) { tmp <-read.csv(files[i]) ggplot(aes(x = Count_norm, y = duration_in_traffic), data = tmp) + geom_point(aes(color = id)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))}
```

I have used `tmp` as the data source, is this incorrect?

Comment: That should be fine. Are you having a problem? The way this is printed, you need a semi colon after the `read.csv()` function. Also, I often wrap my `ggplot()` function in the `print()` function within a loop, though I am not sure this is necessary.

Comment: Good catch on the semicolon post read.csv()! It does indeed run but I don't get any plots. I am using RStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ggplot inside a "print()". This is a requirement when plotting inside a for loop.